# I scrape the review of post but they don't scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scrape the review of post but they don't scrape solve it I am very thankful

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
}

r =requests.get('https://www.realpatientratings.com/botox-cosmetic') 
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
tag = soup.find_all('p',class_='text')
for u in tag:
    print(u.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking xhr requests I found out that you're getting the incorrect page.
Try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
}

r =requests.get('https://www.realpatientratings.com/reviews/procreviewfilters?type=surgical&star=&procedureId=147&sort=new&location=&state=0&within=0') 
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
tag = soup.find_all('p',class_='text')
for u in tag:
    print(u.text)
```

Just changed `https://www.realpatientratings.com/botox-cosmetic` to `https://www.realpatientratings.com/reviews/procreviewfilters?type=surgical&star=&procedureId=147&sort=new&location=&state=0&within=0`

Comment: bro how you check  the link is wrong tell us ??

Comment: brother you say true my link is wrong I changed it will work

Comment: but I know how you  identify my link is wrong

Comment: It will help me in future if you tell me

Comment: Hey, using dev tools(F12 in chrome), then go to network tab. When you've that, go the url(https://www.realpatientratings.com/botox-cosmetic), you'll see all the side-requests made by that url. To check xhr requests go to XHR tab .